# Erro tratamento de caracteres especiais ao enviar para o banco iso-88591 e utf-8

Tags: php, javascript, sql, banco-de-dados, codeigniter

Boa noite amigos,

eu tô com um problema onde não consigo enviar dados corretamente para o banco, quando esses dados vão com caracteres especiais, nome como D'vila sempre dão erros.

Alguém já teve esse problema ou saiba alguma solução.

segue os códigos do model onde é feito o envio para o banco. Usei esse htmlentities para tratar a questão do ' , mas quando vou buscar os dados para mostrar na view acontece erros de visualização.

```
function register_doctor($data)
{

        $key = $this->config->item('encryption_key');

        if($this->db->insert('tbl_doctors', $data))
        {

            $insertid = $this->db->insert_id();

            $this->db->query('Update tbl_doctors SET name = AES_ENCRYPT("'.htmlentities($data['name'], ENT_QUOTES).'","'.$key.'"),
                             cpf = AES_ENCRYPT("'.$data['cpf'].'","'.$key.'"),
                             email = AES_ENCRYPT("'.$data['email'].'","'.$key.'"),
                             password = AES_ENCRYPT("'.$data['password'].'","'.$key.'"),
                             profile_pic = AES_ENCRYPT("'.$data['profile_pic'].'","'.$key.'"),
                             username = AES_ENCRYPT("'.$data['username'].'","'.$key.'"),
                             account_status = 0,
                             date_register = AES_ENCRYPT("'.date('Y-m-d').'","'.$key.'")
                             where id='.$insertid);

            $query = $this->db->get_where("tbl_doctors",array("id"=>$insertid))->row_array();

            $return_array = array('status'=>'success','data'=>$query);

        }
        else
        {

            $return_array = array('status'=>'fail');

        }

    return $return_array;

}
```

Os valores salvam assim no banco como [image: dados no banco]

e queria salvar como exemplo: jonathas d'vila mendonça, tem como fazer isso?

muito obrigado :)

Answer (score 2):

você pode tentar mudar a codificação de caracteres utilizando o php, são:

```
echo 'Teste de charset'.utf8_decode($var);

echo 'Teste de charset'.utf8_encode($var);
```

As documentações oficiais:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php